# Unable to make PyDev work on Eclipe for Jython

Tags: installation, jython

In my PyDev+Eclipse configuration, I tried to run several simple jython modules.

I keep getting the following error:

> ...\Example.py message in console with

Usage: javaw[-options] class[args...]

I tried the suggestion given in PyDev manual - Configure Interpreter/"What if it is not correct": Run

```
java.exe -cp Jython-Path\jythpn.jar org.python.util.jython interpreterInfo.py
```

from command line.

I get the following error:

> IOError: [ErrNo 2} File not found.

In Eclipse plugins folder, I cannot find org.python.util.jython

I have interpreterInfo.py file, but it is with Python, not with Jython.

I am assuming that setting up the environment variables improperly is causing my problem of not being able to run Jython in PyDev.

How do I set them up?

My set up configuration: 
Computer runs on Windows XP
Eclipse: Indigo service release 1
J2SDK: 6 Update 31
Jython: 2.5.2
PyDev: 2.4.0

I shall appreciate any help!

SunKar

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Jython jar is corrupted? (try opening the jython.jar as a zip file and check if the org.python.util.jython.class file is there)

Another thing: when executing:

java.exe -cp Jython-Path\jython.jar org.python.util.jython interpreterInfo.py

are you on the same folder where the interpreterInfo.py is contained?